# Wordpress: code added to functions.php disappears after update

Tags: php, wordpress, updates

Our intranet website has a link which opens a Windows Explorer window from within the page. After a Wordpress update, this functionality was lost. After some Googling I was able to find a solution by adding the following code to the functions.php file:

```
function allowed_link_protocols_filter($protocols)
{
     $protocols[] = 'file';
     return $protocols;
}
add_filter('kses_allowed_protocols', 'allowed_link_protocols_filter');
```

A few days ago, our Wordpress website got another update after which I noticed that the added functionality was removed again (probably overwritten by the new functions.php file of the new version).

How can I add something to functions.php so that I don't have to add it again with every new update that follows?

Please note that, though I know my way around PHP a little bit, I have no Wordpress experience.

Comment: You should extend the theme into a child theme, then edit the functions.php of the child theme. That way changes won't be overridden on update https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Comment: Or, place the functionality into a little custom plugin instead.

Comment: As others have said, do not edit core/theme files, they will get overwritten every time there is an update.

Comment: @jrswgtr Creating a child theme for a single function would be a bit overkill I guess, but thanks for the suggestions. I went for the option CBroe mentioned, and was able to implement it successfully thanks to the excellent guide rank posted. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be to create a child theme of your theme, which will not be overwritten when you update the theme.

But if you just want to add a single function, I would suggest creating a plugin.

1. With FTP go to the folder `wp-content` >> `plugins`
2. Inside the `plugins` folder create a new folder called `my_protocol_filter`
3. Inside of this new created folder, create a php file with the same name `my_protocol_filter.php`
4. Inside of this php file you have to paste the following code

   ```
      <?php /*
      Plugin Name: My custom protocol filter
      Description: Allowed link protocol filter
      Author: Joe
      Version: 1.0
      */
   ```

The comment defines the name of your plugin. Below that you paste your code

```
function allowed_link_protocols_filter($protocols)
{
     $protocols[] = 'file';
     return $protocols;
}
add_filter('kses_allowed_protocols', 'allowed_link_protocols_filter');
```

5. As the folder and the file is in the plugins folder of your wordpress installation (using FTP) you will now find the new plugin in your wordpress backend in the plugins section.
6. Activate the plugin. Your function will now work, no matter what theme you are using or updating.

Comment: Thanks ever so much for the explanation and the easy to follow steps! It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

this is just an update, I found that the best way to put custom javascript is directly through the page it self, in every page there is an editor choose text from it and put your javascript there like below, it work like a charm without causing any conflict.

```
<script> your code here </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but this question is about PHP code, not Javascript.