# Can anyone tell me how to remove the 'proceed to checkout' button from the cart page on my site

Tags: wordpress, checkout

I just want to have paypal checkout, which is working, but the proceed to checkout button causing trouble.
I have tried adding code to the functions.php on my child theme as follows -

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout','woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20);
```

but it doesn't work. Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

`remove_action` was a good idea, may there is something wrong with your child theme or the functions.php. Maybe this function gets called before there comes the function which will add it again.

You can try to hide the button using CSS and the class of the button. Put this in the style.css of your child theme:

```
.wc-proceed-to-checkout { display: none !important; }
```

Another way would be to change the template of your cart, so there is no button inserted.

This requires a view steps.

First create a plugin (if you don't know how, see my answer here: [Wordpress: code added to functions.php disappears after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64754090/wordpress-code-added-to-functions-php-disappears-after-update/64758355#64758355)) with this code:

```
/*****************************************************************************************************************
/**
* Override WooCommerce templates with plugin
*/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_locate_template', 'woo_adon_plugin_template', 1, 3 );
    function woo_adon_plugin_template( $template, $template_name, $template_path ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $_template = $template;
        if ( ! $template_path ) 
            $template_path = $woocommerce->template_url;
    
        $plugin_path  = untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) )  . '/templates/';
    
        // Look within the theme - has priority
        $template = locate_template(
        array(
        $template_path . $template_name,
        $template_name
        )
    );
    
    if( ! $template && file_exists( $plugin_path . $template_name ) )
        $template = $plugin_path . $template_name;
    
    if ( ! $template )
        $template = $_template;

    return $template;
}
```

Inside of your new plugins folder put beside the plugin php file a folder called 'templates' and inside of this another folder called `cart`.

Now go to the woocommerce plugin folder wp-content -> plugins -> woocommerce -> templates -> cart -> and copy the proceed-to-checkout-button.php

Insert the php file inside of the `cart` folder of your custom plugin.
You can now delete the markup of the button

`<a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward"> <?php esc_html_e( 'Proceed to checkout', 'woocommerce' ); ?> </a>`

and save the file.

If you now activate your plugin, the file in your plugin will overwrite the default file of woocommerce. So the button will be missing.